# LXC - quota inside container

Tags: quota, lxc

Is it possible to use disk quota inside a LXC container?

I'm using LVM (`ext4`) as `rootfs` for the container. I don't now how to add the mount options to `/etc/fstab` properly.

The `/etc/fstab` of the container:

`rootfs  /       rootfs  rw,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0     0       0`

This is what `quotacheck -cug /` returns:

`quotacheck: Mountpoint (or device) / not found or has no quota enabled.`
`quotacheck: Cannot find filesystem to check or filesystem not mounted with quota option.`

Output of `mount`:

http://pastebin.com/33AF62pu

Comment: care to elaborate a bit adding, for example, what have you tried so far, how did it fail, etc...?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your root file system is formatted in a file system with quota support, like ext3 or ext4, add `usrquota,grpquota` to `/etc/fstab` entry under options section ([fourth field](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab)), and then run (assuming `/` is the file system mount point)

```
mount -o remount /
```

This assumes there is a separate file system for each LXC instance, else all instances sharing the same file system will be affected.

Make sure that the `quota` program is installed (how this is done varies depending on your OS version)

Comment: I've added more details in question.

`mount: cannot remount block device rootfs read-write, is write-protected`
Maybe AppArmor?

Comment: did you run `# quotacheck -cug /` ? I'm not too familiar with AppArmor, but it could be the culprit check the logs